# Accordion Opens But Won't Close

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation Accordion and I added a script to have smooth opening and closing. It works but the problem is if you have only one panel you can open it but not close it.

Here is the code used:

```
$(".accordion").on("click", "dd:not(.active)", function (event) {
    $("dd.active").removeClass('active').find(".content").slideUp("slow");
    $(this).addClass('active').find(".content").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
$("dd.active").on("click", function (event) {
    $("dd.active").removeClass('active').find(".content").slideUp("slow");
});
```

How do I get this to close smoothly?

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UzeRE/)

Note: Open the Panel then Try to Close It.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `href` from `<dd><a>`.

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $(".accordion").on("click", "dd", function (event) {
        if (!($(this).hasClass("active"))) {
            $("dd.active").removeClass('active').find(".content").slideUp("fast");            
        }
        $(this).toggleClass('active').find(".content").slideToggle("fast");
    })
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/UzeRE/1/)

Comment: The example fiddle is not functioning